# Apache does not work due to MACOSX upgrades to OS X El Capitan?

Tags: macos, apache

Something weird happen to me, the OS X built-in Apache does not work when the MACOSX upgrades to OS X El Capitan(10.11.1).

I have done a lot of search, but still failed to figure out. Here's the system situation:

[image]

When the browser makes a request to `http://localhost`, it gets nothing but shows `Can't connet to server localhost`, any idea to solve this problem.

By the way, Apache does work in MACOSX(10.9).

Comment: check /private/var/log/apache2/error_log

Comment: Thx, but no `error_log` file@sdayal

Comment: check /etc/apache2/httpd.conf for error_log location

Answer (score 0):

I got this problem fixed by the answer of https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/211015/el-capitan-apache-error-message-ah00526

Take the operation below, it does work to me:

We are going to the directory `/etc/apache2/extra`

and take the original `http-mpm.conf` file back:

`sudo mv httpd-mpm.conf httpd-mpm.conf.elcapitan`

`sudo mv httpd-mpm.conf~orig httpd-mpm.conf`

Then we are going to restart `Apache` service, and it works.